# handle vertical page scroll when scrolling horizontally on swiper mobile

Tags: javascript, css, ios, reactjs, swiper.js

I've implemented a swiper in my pet [project](https://doomsday-git-master-dmedov.vercel.app/). Everything looks great except for the part when you try to swipe it on mobile (especially on iOS, I am testing it on iPhone 13 mini). Scroll works but if you just repeat swipe gestures the page starts going up and down a bit depending on the swipe angle and I don't know how to fix it. Feels like the swiper itself is too sensitive or else.

I tried tinkering with shortSwipes and longSwipes and ms but to no avail. Also I tried applying `touch-action: none;` on certain swiper events like transition start or transition end but it still doesn't feel the way I want it to. Only thing I've managed to achieve is to block vertical scroll onTouchStart event on Swiper but it disables vertical scroll completely but I still want to be able to scroll away from swiper when needed.

As an example of what I'm trying to achive, you can take a look at a mobile google search page when googling an [actor](https://www.google.com/search?q=rock%20dwayne&oq=rock&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j46i199i433i465i512j46i433i512j46i3j0i512j46i340i512j69i61.11511j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), you can see a movie carousel there which feels nice and works smoothly. How can I achieve this?

Here's my swiper code:

```
   <Swiper className={`${styles.swiper} ${mobileScrollLock ? styles['swiper-scroll-lock'] : ''}`}
                        onSwiper={setSwiperInstance}
                        onTouchEnd={onTouchEnd}
                        onBeforeTransitionStart={() => setMobileScrollLock(true)}
                        onTransitionEnd={() => setMobileScrollLock(false)}
                        modules={[Mousewheel, FreeMode]}
                        spaceBetween={10}
                        slidesPerView='auto'
                        mousewheel
                        freeMode={{
                            enabled: true,
                            sticky: true,
                        }}
                    >
                        {loading.newPosts && <SwiperSlide className={styles['post-item-spinner']} key='spinner'><Spinner /></SwiperSlide>}
                        {postsData && postsData.map((post: TStory) => {
                            return <SwiperSlide className={styles['swiper-slide']} key={post.id}>
                                <PostItem post={post} />
                            </SwiperSlide>
                        })}
                        {loading.oldPosts && <SwiperSlide className={styles['post-item-spinner']} key='spinner'><Spinner /></SwiperSlide>}
                    </Swiper>
```

and here are the functions used:

```
 const onTouchEnd = (swiper: SwiperType) => {
    if (swiper.progress < 0) checkNewPosts();
    if (-swiper.translate > swiper.snapGrid[swiper.snapGrid.length - 1] + 100 && !limit) {
        setLoading({ postFeed: false, newPosts: false, oldPosts: true });
        addOlderPosts();
    }
}

const enableScroll = () => window.onscroll = null;
const disableScroll = () => {
    const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    window.onscroll = () => window.scroll({ top: scrollTop });
}
```

Comment: I have noticed this problem too. It's annoying, but I have seen examples of swiper on iPhone that don't behave in this way so there should be solution for it. I will let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: Setting cssMode to true fixes this problem, but I opened an issue on GitHub reporting the problem: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/6900

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem got fixed in iOS 16.x. See response to my post here:

https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/6900#issuecomment-1662407556